# How to fix model error when upgrading module in odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I get this error when I try to upgrade my custom module in odoo 13.

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 664, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 345, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 910, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1324, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1312, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-64>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 629, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 471, in load_modules
    env['ir.model.data']._process_end(processed_modules)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1971, in _process_end
    record.unlink()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1190, in unlink
    table=self.env[selection.field_id.model]._table,

 File "/opt/odoo/odoo13/odoo/api.py", line 463, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo13/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'sales.terms'
```

This is the sales.terms model

```py
class SalesTermsAndConditions(models.Model):
    _name = 'sales.terms'
    _description = 'Terms and Conditions'
    _rec_name = 'typex'

    new_type = fields.Selection([
         ('accessories', 'Accessories'),
         ('glass', 'Glass Work'),
         ('aluminium', 'Aluminium profiles'),
         ('projects', 'Projects')
     ], string='Testing')
    d_active = fields.Boolean(string='Active')
    notes = fields.Text()
```

I have a new model named 'sales.terms' I created and I created the corresponding ir.model.access.csv file for it, so I traced down the error and discovered that it isn't the whole model giving causing the error but just the selection field, if i remove the selection field the module upgrades fine.

I am confused as to what might be wrong.

Comment: There is a missing comma after `A test`.

Comment: I have updated the question, that wasnt the issue, I commented those out before

Comment: If you have records with older selections try to remove the records. And sometimes removing the selections (ir.model.field.selection IIRC) could help, too. I had some issues with selections fields in Odoo 13, too, when changing the selection options after creating records.

Comment: @A.Sasori Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @CZoellner Its a new model with no records on it.

Answer (score 0):

The selection seem to be ok. if you rename `new_type` does it then upgrade?
Can you look first errors wen you boot odoo or reload modules

Comment: if I change the field name its still the same thing, I have edited the question and added more error logs

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something missing

```
class SalesTermsAndConditions(models.Model):
    _name = 'sales.terms'
    _description = 'Terms and Conditions'
    _rec_name = 'typex'

    new_type = fields.Selection([
         ('test', 'Test'),
         ('atest', 'A test'), // Comma is missing
         ('accessories', 'Accessories'),
         ('glass', 'Glass Work'),
         ('aluminium', 'Aluminium profiles'),
         ('projects', 'Projects')
     ], string='Testing')
    d_active = fields.Boolean(string='Active')
    notes = fields.Text()
```

Comment: The first 2 selection were not supposed to be there I commented them out, but that's still not the issue, even if i remove them it still gives the error

Comment: If you're in development phase testing it on local just create another db and try again to install your module it will work

Comment: @AdamStrauss that's a good quick solution, but sometimes it's better to invest some time to get behind the error to save time in future developments :-D

Comment: @CZoellner  yeah you're absolutely right but I think this is the only solution :p

Comment: @AdamStrauss Thats the issue it works fine on local, but gives the issue on prod and there is so much data, I can't uninstall the module.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove _rec_name.Replace with some field.

```html
_rec_name = "new_type"
```